# An AVL tree with repeated values and dual comparison

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree

I need to create a data structure (using mainly AVL trees) of objects with two values: level (isn't unique) and id (is unique).

I need to support searching by id, printing by order of levels, as well as merging two such trees and maintain these functionalities with the new tree.

I already have several solutions in mind but I wanted to ask about a specific one:

Will it work to implement this structure with a singular AVL tree where two nodes are first compared according to their level, and then their ids? Mostly I struggle to realize how merging two such trees could work, especially in the case we have tree A where all objects are of level x and tree B where all objects are of level y.

EDIT: Also for searching id in addition there will be a tree only sorted by id.

Could this method work?

Comment: Does `printing by order of levels` mean *print each element from lowest level to highest, order of ids is irrelevant*? You seem to need "2D support". If (*height*) *balanced* wasn't a requirement (please motivate in the question), you could use a search tree on id that is a heap on level.

Answer (score 2):

> singular AVL tree where two nodes are first compared according to their level, and then their ids?

Unfortunately no. If you do that you won't be able to efficiently find a node by its id -- you'll need to look through all possible 'levels', which you didn't specify so I assume they can be unbounded.

I think you may want to insert each node into two separate AVL trees instead. One AVL tree will order the nodes by level, the other by their id. All queries, insertions, deletions and merges can be done on each tree separately.

In other words you'd create two indexes over your data.

In code:

```
struct Node {
    int id;
    int level;

    // by id
    int id_bf;
    Node *id_left, *id_right;

    // by level
    int level_bf;
    Node *level_left, *level_right;
};
```

> EDIT: Also for searching id in addition there will be a tree only sorted by id.

Then you essentially describe the same thing as me. However your tree that's sorted by the composite `(level, id)` key is wasteful; all you need is a tree sorted by `(level)` and a tree sorted by `(id)` (scalar keys). There's no need, among the operations you provided, to sort by `(level, id)` and `(id)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply unfortunately I just forgot to mention that additionally I will have a tree sorted by id for this functionality.

I thought of you solution I've just been wondering about this particular solution a classmate told me which I think will not work because of the merging,

Comment: @user3917631: a tree sorted by (level, id) is also sorted by (level). Thus if you have a tree sorted by (id) in addition to either of those, you'll be able to do the operations efficiently just like I described. It is a bit wasteful to sort by (level, id) if all you need is (level).

Comment: I know, I am only asking out of interest, can it work? Is it possible to have two trees sorted by (level, id) both integers and merge them in O(n) (n number of combined nodes).

Comment: @user3917631: yes it is possible, and not different from merging two trees sorted by anything else. Binary search trees are comparison based, so they don't 'care' what you're using for your key as long as it's a [totally ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). A tuple of integers is a TO set. Wikipedia article on AVL trees describes how to do efficient merge; [there it's called a union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Set_operations_and_bulk_operations). However you may want to store node height instead of a balance factor to do that.